# i want to open an image in another activity when clicked on the item in the listview

Tags: android, listview

I wrote the following code but I am sure that I did something wrong in the method onItemClick()
My listview is displaying properly and when clicked upon another activity opens I want to show only the image in the new activity
so need some help from you guys

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String[] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",
        "Saturday", "Sunday" };
int[] images = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher };

int[] images1 = { R.drawable.image01, R.drawable.image02,
        R.drawable.image03, R.drawable.image04, R.drawable.image05,
        R.drawable.image06, R.drawable.image07 };
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArjAdapter adapter = new ArjAdapter(getBaseContext(), days, images);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            File imgfile = new File("");
            if (imgfile.exists()) {
                String myBitmap = imgfile.getAbsolutePath();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        ImageActivity.class);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra("img", "images1");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

in the above method , i am not sure what to include inside the file object , this method i saw somewhere but i was not sure what to include inside it , so left blank to consult from you guys

ImageActivity , in which i want to display the image

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity {
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.images);

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getIntent().getStringExtra(
            "img"));

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

any suggestions are welcomed

Comment: you mean you wan to show clicked image which is in images1[] array right?

Comment: 7 items on listview and 7 images in my images1[] , when clicked on respective item respective image should be displayed in my ImageActivity , yes

Comment: I post the answer just try and let me know what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write `onListItemClick()` like this

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        ImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("img", images1[position]);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
```

**ImageActivity.java**

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.images);


        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        iv.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("img", 0));
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

Comment: sir just a blank activity opens up

Comment: yes sir , i even declared  <data android:mimeType="image/*" /> in my manifest file

Comment: It is not required remove it

Comment: but still a blank activity sir

Answer (score 0):

here you didnt define any location of your image. define the location string and put in the file and check it.

```
String location="storage/img1.jpg";

File imgfile = new File(location);
```

Comment: sir i dont want to display a specific image , i want to display 7 different images when clicked on the respective items accordingly , thats why i have initialized an array of images and placed the images inside drawable folder , so according to you if i want to access the images through file  , how should i specify the location ??