# Open Different image in second activity by clicking different buttons(names of images) in first activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity, imageview

I have two activities. Activity one, with three buttons having names of images i.e. a,b,c. I want to open that particular image in second activity which named button I have clicked in first activity. I dont wanted to make three different activities for opening three different images. Please help me in it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (maybe try the search box at the top of the page) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question as well as [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i want to open an image in another activity when clicked on the item in the listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629678/i-want-to-open-an-image-in-another-activity-when-clicked-on-the-item-in-the-list)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use extras while intent like so:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context,NewActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("name",value of variable);
      startActivity(intent);
```

Then in NewActivity do this:

```
String colorName=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
switch(name){
case "color1":
do something;
break;
case "color2":
do something;
break;
case "color3":
do something;
break;
}
```