# Android - How to open image in new activity by buttons id?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to create an app; when I click a button it will open an image on second activity.

For example

```
"button1"->"image1" ,

 "button2"->"image2"
```

but I couldn't. Have a method to do it?

Comment: do you want to pass data from one activity to another? ,Like in your case Image.

Comment: Check the below link it has a very good example.<br>
[open-an-image-in-another-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629678/i-want-to-open-an-image-in-another-activity-when-clicked-on-the-item-in-the-list)

Answer (score 1):

In your MainActivity implement an OnClickListener for the button:

```
private Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourItemIdInXml);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // put Intent here
        }
    });
}
```

Inside the onClick create an intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (CurrentActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);
```

and put your imageId (supposing your image is in the drawables folder and has and ID) into intent:

```
intent.putExtra("IMAGE", imageId);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the receiving activitys onCreate method accept this intent:

```
private ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

    int imageId = getIntent().getIntExtra("IMAGE", 0); // 0 is a default value
                                                       // IMAGE is a string that serves as a key, can be anything just make sure it's the same as in putExtra()
}
```

And after you can create an imageview and set it using the imageId:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageIdInXml);
image.setImageResource(imageId);
```

And do the same for the second button.

It's basically the same answer as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629678/i-want-to-open-an-image-in-another-activity-when-clicked-on-the-item-in-the-list) just a bit more detailed.